# Override default Console help text

Tags: symfony, console-application

I want to cleanly override part of the default text output by `Symfony\Component\Console` when either the `help` or `list` command is used.  In particular, the gratuitous line wrap of the verbosity option bugs me a lot although I may ultimately want to alter the rest of the help/list text a bit as well.

I.e. this line of output:

`--verbose        -v|vv|vvv Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug.`

Would be nicer if I could change it to something like:

`--verbose        -v|vv|vvv Set verbosity level.`

I could subclass `Symfony\Component\Console\Application` and override the `getDefaultInputDefinition()` method.

I perhaps could use a combination of `getDefinition()` and `setDefinition()` to fiddle with the `InputDefinition` object.

But these don't seem to be very maintainable.

Is there some other, better, way to accomplish this?

Comment: "Verbosity levels" doesn't explain anything about the option, it just repeats the option name and value...

Comment: It's a filler example.  I could have said "Lorem ipsum dolor".  The point was, as a long-time Unix command line user, I find Console's default help and list text to be inconsistent and ugly.  I want to change it to conform with most Unix commands.

Comment: I find Console's default help to be _helpful_ - more important than looking pretty or conforming to standards. That said, you make a valid point and it should be possible to override these in a maintainable way.

Comment: It is helpful.  But I want the default to be terse, and the "help" to be more verbose.  Most of the time, programmers using a tool only need a brief reminder of the available options, rather than a more elaborate description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. I'm not certain it will work but looks like the closest solution.

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;

public function overrideVerboseInputOption(Application $application)
{
    $verboseOption = $application->getDefinition()->getOption('verbose');

    $customVerboseOption = new InputOption(
        $verboseOption->getName(),
        $verboseOption->getShortcut(),
        InputOption::VALUE_NONE,
        "Set verbosity level"
    );

    $options =& $application->getDefinition()->getOptions();

    unset($options['verbose']);

    $application->getDefinition()->addOption($customVerboseOption);
}
```

Comment: It throws the following error.  I'll try to make it work.  

```Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message 'Cannot set a default value when using InputOption::VALUE_NONE mode.' in ../vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Input/InputOption.php:162```

Comment: @CXJ Apologies, I had the arguments order incorrect. I've edited the code, try now :)

Comment: Cool! You're welcome. It was a shot in the dark so I'm pleased it works